# Find the elongation in the wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

> Two wires of diameter 0.25 cm, one made of steel and the other made of brass are loaded as shown in fig. The unloaded length of steel wire is 1.5 m and that of brass wire is 1.0 m. Compute the elongation of the steel and the brass wires.

I'm having problem with brass that since it is not connected to a rigid support so then how to calculate the elongation in the brass wire? I think their will be less elongation in brass wire in this situation as compared to a situation where the brass wire is connected to a rigid support. Am I right? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you are wrong. The elongation of the brass wire is independent of what it is hanging from. Whether it is hanging from a slinky or a freeway overpass it is supporting the same mass so it is subjected to the same force and therefore the same elongation (assuming static equilibrium).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Brass is being pulled by one weight.  Steel by two weights.
If you have trouble visualizing this, imagine you are hanging from a trapeze and from a tree.  Does your weight change depending on where you hang from?